# Braintree working on local, not on Server

Tags: php, slim, braintree

I am getting an error when I call Braintree_ClientToken::generate(); in a Slim Framework api call which looks like

```
$app->get('/api/getClientToken', function() use ($dbh){
//$clientToken = "myToken";
  Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
  echo json_encode($clientToken);
```

This error only occurs on my amazon web server (its a POST Server 500 error).  When I call the api call on my local setup, the call returns my client token fine.

I call these functions too earlier before the api call is made (in my start.php file)

```
  Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
  Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('--');
  Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('--');
  Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('--');
```

Comment: have you checked the server logs for more detailed error information?

Comment: Yes, I am getting "Call to undefined function Braintree\\curl_init() in //path..."

Comment: It sounds like the server cannot find the Braintree dependency - recheck your server deployment package to make sure it is there, and that any required dependency paths are set.

Comment: can you check weather `php-curl` is installed or not.

Comment: @chetanameta that was the error, i found it awhile ago.  I dont know how but my curl got uninstalled on my server.  Kicked over my chair.

Comment: so i should put the answer :P

Comment: Yes @ChetanAmeta: you should create an answer for this. :)

Comment: I'll add an answer purely because I've just had the same thing... Client _assured_ me Curl was installed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like cURL isn't installed.

Run `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` and then restart Apache.